# Allow users to drop owned prefix database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, wildcard, prefix

Using phpMyAdmin I created a user with all permissions granted on prefixed (eg. user_db) databases. Everything works as I would want it to, except for one thing. How do I allow users to drop the prefixed databases they have permissions for? I can't seem to find where to do that, IF that's possible at all.

EDIT:

Note that the users are permitted to drop the database, I just can't seem to find where they should do that in phpMyAdmin as for example the root user would by selecting a database from the list and then clicking 'drop'.

EDIT 2:

This is how adding a user looks for me:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select the database, on the right side panel at the top, there is a menu called "Operations", there you can find the "Drop the database (DROP)" option.

[image]

---

You will need to edit your `config.inc.php` file of your `phpMyAdmin` with:

```
$cfg['AllowUserDropDatabase'] = TRUE;
```

This will show the link on the operation menu like on the above image.

Keep in mind there is a lot other options you can manually add as well that can be seen at http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#AllowUserDropDatabase

Comment: Yes, usually there is. But when I log into the user's account in phpMyAdmin, it doesn't show for me. And I know for sure that all required privileges are set properly.

Comment: @GabiBarrientos can you update your question and show how you are creating and giving privileges to the user ?

Comment: Edited and uploaded an image